# Rollback a clj-record transaction

Tags: database, transactions, clojure

I'm using clj-record/transaction two wrap two record creations. On error, I'm using clojure.contrib.condition/raise to throw an exception but this doesn't roll anything back. Any ideas?

Comment: I should note that I'm raising an exception on an application error, not a referential integrity issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use clojure.contrib.sql/set-rollback-only:

```
(ns my.namespace.txtest
  (:use clojure.contrib.condition)
  (:require clj-record.boot
    [clj-record.callbacks.built-ins     :as cb]
    [clj-record.core                    :as rec]
    [clj-record.validation.built-ins    :as valid]
    [clojure.contrib.sql                :as sql]))

(def db {:classname "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    :subprotocol "mysql" 
    :user "mydb" 
    :password "password" 
    :subname "//localhost/mydb"})

(defn do-something
  (rec/transaction db
    (do-something)
    (if (some-error-test)
      (do
        (sql/set-rollback-only)
        (raise :type "some-error" :message "Oops")))))
```